# xarray ERROR : ValueError: did not find a match in any of xarray's currently installed IO backends

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to open a RINEX dataset using xarray. Although I have already installed both 'netcfd4' and 'scipy', I am getting the following value error.

```
ValueError: did not find a match in any of xarray's currently installed IO backends ['netcdf4', 'scipy']. Consider explicitly selecting one of the installed engines via the ``engine`` parameter, or installing additional IO dependencies, see:
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/getting-started-guide/installing.html
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/io.html
```

When I again try to install scipy and netcdf4 i get the following messeage.

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: netcdf4 in c:\users\sdasgupta.student\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (1.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from netcdf4) (1.21.5)
Requirement already satisfied: cftime in c:\users\sdasgupta.student\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from netcdf4) (1.6.2)
```

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\sdasgupta.student\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (1.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.26.0,>=1.18.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scipy) (1.21.5)
```

I have uninstall and install xarray, scipy and netcdf4 but still it is giving me the same error.

Comment: make sure you install the necessary dependencies so that you can work with a suitable engine you could try using `python -m pip install "xarray[complete]"`

Comment: how did you install these packages? I'd recommend using conda, which is better than pip at installing non-python dependencies like netCDF. If you have anaconda installed, I'd recommend deleting it and starting over with miniconda, which doesn't pollute your base environment with a bunch of packages from conflicting channels. or better yet, use [`miniforge`](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) (or it's faster cousin `mambaforge` on the same page), which set the conda-forge channel as the default.

Comment: @ellhe-blaster thanks!! it's still giving the same error.

Answer (score 5):

**Check if the file exists.**

Per this answer on `xarray` github: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/6335#issuecomment-1199282081

> Since folks have asked questions since this was closed (and I had a similar issue), this ValueError exception can be raised in a misleading way if the file being specified does not exist. The exception implies that it is a file format error, but it may just not exist.